# Firefox css :active not working together with sortable (works in IE & chrome)

Tags: css, jquery-ui, firefox, jquery-ui-sortable

It's much easier explained with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ymt9azmm/

Problem: (In firefox) The cursor doesn't change to "Pointer" as I click the td for moving the row in the table using jquery sortable: http://bit.ly/1sM8ewX

It works in Chrome, and IE- so open the fiddle file In Chrome and see the difference

Html:

```
<table border="1" id="sortable">
    <tbody class="ui-sortable">
        <tr id="order-4" style="opacity: 1;" class="">
            <td class="handle ui-sortable-handle"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</td>
            <td>name1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="order-4" style="opacity: 1;" class="">
            <td class="handle ui-sortable-handle"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</td>
            <td>name2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
#sortable td:hover { 
    cursor: s-resize;
}
#sortable td:active{ 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

js: (Also jquery && jquery-ui)

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable tbody" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});
```

To sum in up:
The css: `#sortable td:active{cursor: pointer;}` Doesn't work in FireFox
The cursor doesn't change to pointer.

How can I make it work also in firefox?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps at all, but it's not liking your jquery. If you take out the following two lines, it works:

```
$("#sortable tbody").sortable();
$("#sortable").disableSelection();
```

Comment: @Lenzi_Gall Well I kinda need those lines...At least the first one is a must- I would like a grabbing animation whenever the user moving/dragging the table rows.